# How to handle Exception while processing two third party APIs in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, namecheap

I am building Saas app using Laravel and I worried about this case.

I am integrating Namecheap Domain Purchase API & Paypal Payment Gateway API.

My logic is like this

```
-Show Available Domains:
-Customer picks one:
-Customer pays with paypal (redirect to paypal page):
-If payment is success, I will call domain register API.
-If success, then I will show success message.
```

Above is the perfect case that everything is working as I expected.

But here is my concern.

```
...
-Customer pays with paypal (redirect to paypal page):
-Payment was success, I will call domain register API.
-Domain register API is not success: (maybe i need to refund?)
```

Other option:

```
-Customer pays with paypal (redirect to paypal page):
-Before do actual payment on my side, I will call domain register API.
-If domain register AIP is success, I will do actual payment process.
```

In this case too, if actual payment process is failed, then the customers will be able to get domain for free.

Can anyone give me some advice to tackle these cases?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you're checking availability up front, but you should always process the payment before registering the domain. If registration fails, you can immediately refund or offer the choice of another domain or whatever works.

For payment approval, the best PayPal approval flow is: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

This calls two routes on your server, one for 'Set Up Transaction' and one for 'Capture Transaction', documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/

- If the capture succeeds on the server, that is where you would then
  register the domain and respond with success.  If the registration
  fails, that is where you would refund or offer other options.
- If the capture did not succeed, that is where you would propagate the
  failure message to be handled appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. 
In Set Up Transaction, what should I do on my server side?

Comment: Return an order id, https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/set-up-transaction/